# Why are SwiftUI buttons in a HStack and LazyHGrid spacing out incorrectly?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have recently developed an iPadOS app on Xcode, and it is now on the app store. However, one user reported a problem with the app. During my testing, and on some iPads, it works fine, like [image: this.]

However, the user, using a 8th Generation iPad 2, saw a different screen, like
[image: this.]

The problem is especially noticeable in the HStack with the 123, Delete, Clear, and Space buttons and also in the alphabet grid (LazyGrid).
The code:

`

```
Other Code

var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                switch view {
                case "text":
                Button(action: {
                    view = "number"
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: g.size.width/4, height: g.size.height/2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .border(.gray, width: 1)
                    Text("123")
                        .font(.system(size: g.size.width/30))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                case "number":
                    Button(action: {
                        view = "text"
                    }) {
                        ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: g.size.width/4, height: g.size.height/2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .border(.gray, width: 1)
                        Text("ABC")
                            .font(.system(size: g.size.width/30))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                default:
                    Text("Error")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    text = ""
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: g.size.width/4, height: g.size.height/2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .border(.gray, width: 1)
                    Text("Clear")
                        .font(.system(size: g.size.width/30))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                Button(action: {
                    if text != "" {
                    text.remove(at: text.index(before: text.endIndex))
                                                }
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: g.size.width/4, height: g.size.height/2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .border(.gray, width: 1)
                    Text("Delete")
                        .font(.system(size: g.size.width/30))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                Button(action: {
                    text += " "
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: g.size.width/4, height: g.size.height/2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .border(.gray, width: 1)
                    Text("Space")
                        .font(.system(size: g.size.width/30))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            }
            .offset(y: -g.size.height/2)
        }
    }

Other Code
```

`

I have already set spacing in the HStack to 0, expecting it to remove the space between the buttons, but it has no effect on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually on the user's end. They had turned on "button shapes" in their accessibility settings, which made the buttons have an extra border.

Comment: that's a valid user option

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to simplify the code and use stacks to your advantage.
The key to this is to let the buttons expand to fill space by using .frame(maxWidth:.infinity) instead of the default behavior which is to fit to the content.

```
struct KeysViews: View {
 var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment:.center,spacing: 1.0) {
        HStack (spacing:1.0) {
            but("123")
            but("Clear")
            but("Space")
        }.frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
        HStack (spacing:1.0) {
            ForEach(["A","B","C","D","E",","],id:\.self) {c in
                but(c)
            }
        }
        HStack (spacing:1.0) {
            ForEach(["F","J","H","I","J","."],id:\.self) {c in
                but(c)
            }
        }
        HStack (spacing:1.0) {
            ForEach(["K","L","M","N","O","!"],id:\.self) {c in
                but(c)
            }
        }
        HStack (spacing:1.0) {
            ForEach(["P","Q","R","S","T","?"],id:\.self) {c in
                but(c)
            }
        }
    }.frame(maxWidth:.infinity).background(.gray).padding()
}

func but(_ text : String) -> some View {
    Button(text, action: {}).frame(maxWidth:.infinity).background(.white)
}
}
```

[image: On iPad]
[image: On iPhone]

Comment: Do you know why my original code worked on devices such as iPad Pro 12.9 in, but no on iPad 2? They both have the same version number.

Comment: My guess would be that it has something to do with DPI and mapping points to pixeels. The iPad had a DPI of 132 whereas modern iPads are more in the range of 250. It doesn't fully explain the image you're seeing, but in a nutshell when you say a border of 1 point, iOS needs to figure out how many pixels to light up. Ideally iOS should maintain a similar physical size between different devices, i.e. 1 point should equal 4 pixel on iPad Pro and 0.01" and 1 pixel on iPad 2 and still 0.01", but it seems like something isn't working quite right. Also what's iOS version running the iPad 2?

Comment: You can read more about coordinate spaces and mapping between physical and logical devices here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: The iOS version is 15.6.1

Comment: The general problem seems to be a faint automatic oval border around the buttons that is spacing them out, however, I did not add this.

Comment: Is that because of the iPad's UI, rather than the pixels? Buttons have automatic borders in macOS. Could that be related?

Comment: Did you try creating an iPad 2 simulator and see if you can debug it?

Comment: I cannot download the iPad 2, Retina, Air, and Mini 2, and 3 on Xcode for some reason, so I can't debug. When I try to add an iPad 2 sim, under "OS Version," it writes: iOS 14.0 (14.0.1 - 18A384) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0, instead of just iOS 14.0. I don't know why that is happening either.

Comment: This turned out not to be a problem with my code but rather with the iPad in question. The user had turned on button shapes in accessibility, which changed the appearance of the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that's great to know. Might be worth updating the question so other people might find this when encountering similar issues.